# Render jpeg buffer using html5 with VC# code ( MVC Application)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html

I want to render jpeg buffer on all browser window.
JPEG Buffer is receiving from server using http request.
I want to implement this using VC# with html5 ( MVC Application).
Can you guide me how can i do this ?

Comment: what do you mean with jpeg buffer. a jpeg bytestream you want to display on the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, hope i got you right.. You have a byte[] buffer that originally was an JPEG encoded Image? To render it in a view, just ebmed it as a base64 string:

```
@model System.Byte[]
@{
    string filetype = "jpeg";
}
<img src="@String.Format("data:image/{0};base64,{1}", filetype, Convert.ToBase64String(Model)))" alt="Something" />
```